# C# Map all possible characters to the alphabet

Tags: c#, string, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

I'm trying to map all possible letters to the letters A-Z, # for numbers and maybe & for other characters.
For that I'm using the `Normalize(NormalizationForm)` method.
That gets rid of most of the unwanted characters like characters with accents and so on.

However it doesn't deal with duplicates. It seems like the letter M is located in more than one position and therefore the equal-check fails.

Here's my code that checks every possible letter:

```
for (uint i = char.MinValue; i <= char.MaxValue; i++)
{
    char normalizedChar = char.ToUpper($"{(char)i}".Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKD).FirstOrDefault());
    if (Char.IsLetter((char)i) && !allowedLetters.Contains(normalizedChar))
        throw new Exception();
}
```

Where allowedLetters is a char array containing all letters of the alphabet and '#'.

It fails at i = 181 which is normalized 924 = 'M' just like 77 = 'M'.

I'm also open for better ways to normalize a character since the only method I could find only works on strings.

Comment: What do you mean by "all possible letters"? Unicode letters include Latin, Greek, Cyrillic, Hebrew, Arabic, etc. I don't see how you could map all of those to A-Z without getting some duplicates.

Comment: well a char is 2 bytes wide so if you'd take a look at the for loop I'm going through every possible value and if Char.IsLetter is true I check if the normalized character is in the allowedLetters array which contains the characters 'A'-'Z'.
And what do you mean by duplicates.
As I said my problem are those duplicates and I'd like to map them to one value.

Comment: OK. The number 181 is the Unicode "MICRO SIGN" µ. What do you want the "normalized" character to be?

Comment: Also, the $"{(char)i}" doesn't look correct.

Comment: as I said the normalized character is M but it's a different M than my M and therefore it fails in the Contains.
It is correct. Lookup C# 6.0 changes. Probably not the fastest or best way to create a string from an int char but less text than toString() and I don't care about performance since it's just a test code.

Comment: it seems that 924 is the greek letter Mu which just looks exactly the same.
so I guess I have to convert the greek letters to latin letters - though I don't really get why it fails at M and A-L don't throw anything.

Comment: I think you will hit the same problem with other uppercase Greek letters. They are just higher in the Unicode range.

Answer (score 1):

The [NormalizationForm MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.normalizationform(v=vs.110).aspx) explicitly warns about this:

> **Some Unicode sequences are considered equivalent because they represent the same character.**  (...)
>   **However, ordinal, that is, binary, comparisons consider these sequences different because they contain different Unicode code values.** Before performing ordinal comparisons, applications must normalize these strings to decompose them into their basic components.

That note about "applications must normalize" means that you have some work to perform in your application. I suspect you're going to have to do some hand-mapping, ex `map[char(924)] = char(77)` or similar.

Comment: Unfortunately using an hardcoded table to map the other characters wouldn't work since Char.IsLetter seems to accept multiple thousand characters that are normalized not part of the latin alphabet.
I guess I'll just map all characters that are not normalized to a latin latter to some other character.

Comment: although there seems to be a way since the app list in Windows 10 sorts those letters as expected. ĸ is mapped to K although the normalization doesn't change it. (Though that doesn't make much sense since they afaik only look pretty close)

Comment: Are you sorting, or just normalizing to Latin characters, or what? You're not presenting a clear picture of your end goal here.

Comment: does that matter in any way?
I'm working on a JumpList similiar to the Windows Startmenu > All Apps one if you want to know.